# read ArrayList with index

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class which returns an array list, but when I'm reading it I want to write the values in a page.

**I have this class:**

```
        public ArrayList users(string table)
        {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            foreach (DataRow item in com.Execute("select * from " + table + ";").Rows)
            {
                list.Add(item["id"].ToString());
                list.Add(item["mail"].ToString());
                list.Add(item["data"].ToString());
            }

            return list;
        }
```

**Page_Load**

```
loadUsersNewsletter lun = new loadUsersNewsletter();
String[] myArr = (String[])lun.users("newsletter").ToArray(typeof(string));
foreach (Object o in myArr)
{
    load.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td>" + o + "</td><td>" + o + "</td></tr>"));
    ...
}
```

How can I read the values by index, or another way, in order to not repeat values?
If there is another solution for this please tell me.

Comment: maybe if i could read the array 3 in 3 i could read without repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Change the `users` method like :

```
public List<string[]> users(string table)
    {
        List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
        foreach (DataRow item in com.Execute("select * from " + table + ";").Rows)
        {
            list.Add(new string[]{item["id"].ToString(), item["mail"].ToString(), 
                                                    item["data"].ToString()});
        }

        return list;
    }
```

and :

```
loadUsersNewsletter lun = new loadUsersNewsletter();
List<string[]> myArr = lun.users("newsletter");
foreach (string[] o in myArr)
 {
   load.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td>" + o[0] + "</td><td>" + o[1] 
                                        + "</td><td>" + o[2] + "</td></tr>"));
 }
```

Comment: list.Add(new string{item["id"].ToString(), item["mail"].ToString(), item["data"].ToString()}); this has an error: string does not contain a definition to Add

Comment: @DiogoSeveriano Huh? are you sure?

Comment: @DiogoSeveriano Sorry! forgot the `[]` after `new string`

Answer (score 0):

try using `Distinct`, something like this :

```
foreach (var o in myArr.Distinct())
{
    load.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td>" + o + "</td><td>" + o + "</td></tr>"));
    ...
}
```

or if you are loading the data from a database, you might consider doing it on the database server, i.e, instead of this :

```
"select * from table"
```

try this :

```
"select distinct * from table"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code, if you want to eliminate duplicates.

```
String[] myArr = (String[])lun.users("newsletter").ToArray(typeof(string));
    List<string> Content=new List<string>();
    foreach (Object o in myArr)
    {
        if(Content.Contains(o.ToString()))
    continue;
    Content.Add(o.ToString());
        load.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr><td>" + o + "</td><td>" + o + "</td></tr>"));
        ...
    }
```